# Does Ask Different have a different tag-suggester than other SE sites?

Tags: support, tags, editing, asking-questions

I’m using an old version of IOS Safari (original iPad).  Of course, there a lot of minor irritations with the UI.  One of them is that on all SE sites, selecting a suggested tag takes anywhere from two taps to more than I’m willing to retry.

Except here.  Here, “it just works.”

Is it different JavaScript?

---

(edit)
Sigh.  Never mind.  Until now, I selected a tag with one tap every time in the site only.  This time, I gave up after ten taps.

Comment: Are you using the mobile version of the site?

Comment: Don't remember, but I doubt it.